# How to make code program for calculating implicit equation using iteration technique

Tags: equation-solving

I have a problem to calculate implicit equation in *Mathematica*, as follows:

$$
\theta_1=\arctan\left[\frac{u_2A_2}{u_1A_1}\tan(\phi-\theta_1)\right]
$$

My data are as follows:

```
A1 = {506.02, 508.7};
A2 = {502.386, 504.43};
u1 = {-0.12, -0.11};
u2 = {0.10, 0.12};
```

I try to make code program like this:

```
angle = Table[x /. FindRoot[x == N[ArcTan[(A2 U2)/(A1 U1) Tan[64` - x]]/Degree], 
                            {x, 0.5}, PrecisionGoal -> 1
                           ], 
              {i, 2}
             ]
```

But after Evaluating, I can not succeed. How to fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you mean by "not succeed"?

Comment: @ItamarG3, I can not get result

Comment: Your coefficients are vectors and your unknown is a single scalar.  The two sides cannot be equal in this form.

Comment: These equations have no real solutions for your inputs.

Comment: I solve my problem using this :Table[L /. 
   FindRoot[
    L == ArcTan[(A2[[i]]*U2[[i]] Tan[(63.8 - L) Degree])/(
       A1[[i]]*U1[[i]])]/Degree, {L, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 8], {i, 1, Length[time]}];

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the dot product of the vector pairs A1, U1 and A2, U2.
Also, you need to give `FindRoot` two starting values that are close to different roots to get two distinct answers.

```
angle =
  x /.   
    FindRoot[x == N[ArcTan[(A2.U2)/(A1.U1) Tan[64 - x]]/Degree], {x, #}] & /@ 
     {-2, 1}
```

> `{-2.0104, 1.19002}`

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem:
I use this equation to solve implicit equation:

```
Table[L /.FindRoot[L == 
ArcTan[(A2[[i]]*U2[[i]] Tan[(63.8 - L) Degree])/(A1[[i]]*U1[[i]])]/Degree, {L, 2}, AccuracyGoal -> 10,PrecisionGoal -> 8], {i, 1, Length[time]}]
```